# JSON / POJO validation

Tags: java, json, hibernate, validation, jackson

I have a service that receives a `JSON`. The requirement is to parse it to it's corresponding `POJO` and validate it's fields.

- Parsing: I am using Jackson's `ObjectMapper`
- Validation: I am using `Hibernate Validation API (JSR-303)`.

  ```
  public class Person {

  @JsonProperty(value = "firstName", required = true)
  private final @NotBlank @Size(max = 20) String firstName;

  @JsonProperty(value = "lastName", required = true)
  private final @NotBlank @Size(max = 30) String lastName;

  @JsonProperty(value = "gender", required = true)
  private final Gender gender; // enum

  @JsonProperty(value = "dateOfBirth", required = true)
  @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyyMMdd")
  private final Date dateOfBirth;

  // ctor and getters
  }
  ```

I have a factory class that should create `POJO` objects from `JSON`.

```
public class PersonFactory {

    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // plus all the setup

    public Person createFromJson(JsonNode json) throws JsonProcessingException {
        return mapper.treeToValue(json, Person.class);
    }   
}
```

And a validator class that validates the object and creates a custom report.

```
public class PersonValidator {

    private static final Validator validator =
         Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();

    public PersonReport validate(Person person) {
        Set<ConstraintViolation<Person>> viols = validator.validate(); 
        // ... and the logic to create the actual PersonReport 
        // from the constraint violations result
        return report;
    }
}
```

The problem about this is that the `PersonReport` should contain **all** the validation issues that occurred, and that means **both** the problems that can occur during JSON processing (contained by `JsonProcessingException`) **and** the validation of fields.

`PersonReport` shouldn't make any difference where the validation failed (in the processing of JSON or the validation of fields) and should catch all those errors to a single report.

What would be the best place to put the `PersonValidator` in this architecture?

Is something like:

```
try {
    Person p = PersonFactory.createFromJson(json).withValidator(validator);
} catch (PersonParseException e) {
    PersonReport report = e.getReport();
}
```

a good design? Because it kind of mixes validation with creation, but yet both my validation and creation logic can indicate the illegal format of input JSON.

That way a `PersonFactory` would be like this:

```
public class PersonFactory {

    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // plus all the setup

    public Person createFromJson(JsonNode json, Validator validator) throws PersonParseException {
        Person p = null;
        try {
            p = mapper.treeToValue(json, Person.class);
        } catch(JsonProcessingException e) {
            PersonReport report = createReport(e);
            throw new PersonParseException(report);
        }

        Set<ConstraintViolation<Person>> viols = validator.validate(p);

        if (viols.size() != 0) {throw new PersonParseException(createReport());}

        return person;

    }   
}
```

Is there any better way to do that, so that the creation and validation are not mixed, but yet can catch all the illegal format errors?

Comment: So you want to add the exceptions details as well in report along with validations report but even you follow any architecture it will be incomplete bcoz while parsing it will take u out after first exception... Then you will have to either continue with all the further nodes else quit your report with halfly parsed json

Comment: @Rohan Kadu I get your point. Do you have any advice how to parse whole of it?